# Access Nested Python Object returns None

Tags: python

I'am struggling to access the nested 'is_bot' attribute inside 'from' of the **update** object down below:

```
{'message': {'caption_entities': [],
             'channel_chat_created': False,
             'chat': {'first_name': 'Rodrigo Formighieri',
                      'id': 446924384,
                      'type': 'private',
                      'username': 'rodrigoformi'},
             'date': 1516040454,
             'delete_chat_photo': False,
             'entities': [{'length': 7, 'offset': 0, 'type': 'bot_command'}],
             'from': {'first_name': 'Rodrigo Formighieri',
                      'id': 446924384,
                      'is_bot': False,
                      'language_code': 'pt-BR',
                      'username': 'rodrigoformi'},
             'group_chat_created': False,
             'message_id': 145,
             'new_chat_member': None,
             'new_chat_members': [],
             'new_chat_photo': [],
             'photo': [],
             'supergroup_chat_created': False,
             'text': '/invite'},
 'update_id': 241263441}
```

What I have Tried:

```
   update.get('message',{}).get('from',{}).is_bot
```

This up returns *AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'get'*

```
   update["message"]["from"]["is_bot"]
```

This last returns *TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable*

Don't know what to do anymore. Any help?

Comment: Your first attempt fails because `is_bot` isn't an attribute, it's a dictionary key, so you use subscripting to get it (`['is_bot']`).  Your second attempt works for me without any errors.

Comment: Your second attempt works fine for me as well. There must be something you're not showing us that's wrong.

Comment: It is an attribute as other suggest, here is a link to use a json object https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-json-data-using-python--cms-25758.

Comment: What is a Message object? Where does it come from?

Comment: my first should be update.get('message',{}).get('from',{}).get('is_bot', "") then? My second ALWAYS returns That error I showed.

Comment: ayahan, this update object comes from python-telegram-bot. When I use it directly I have the errors. But if I export it's string and make as Matej said in the below answer, it works. Still doesnt know why this happens.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    d = {'message': {'caption_entities': [],
             'channel_chat_created': False,
             'chat': {'first_name': 'Rodrigo Formighieri',
                      'id': 446924384,
                      'type': 'private',
                      'username': 'rodrigoformi'},
             'date': 1516040454,
             'delete_chat_photo': False,
             'entities': [{'length': 7, 'offset': 0, 'type': 'bot_command'}],
             'from': {'first_name': 'Rodrigo Formighieri',
                      'id': 446924384,
                      'is_bot': False,
                      'language_code': 'pt-BR',
                      'username': 'rodrigoformi'},
             'group_chat_created': False,
             'message_id': 145,
             'new_chat_member': None,
             'new_chat_members': [],
             'new_chat_photo': [],
             'photo': [],
             'supergroup_chat_created': False,
             'text': '/invite'},
 'update_id': 241263441}

is_bot = d.get('message').get('from').get('is_bot')

print (is_bot) # False
```

Comment: This works. But I cant do this in my code. When I do ast.literal_eval(update), It returns the errors:
raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <telegram.update.Update object at 0x00000000045A44E0>. What is interesting is that when I just print(update) and I get it's string from the bash and then do exactly what you did in your answer with the string, It Works. I'am going mad!!!

Comment: instead of eval, try: dict(your_string) to create a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

When I or my students struggle with getting to a deeply nested value, I often step through it to ensure that I am getting, seeing what I expect. As several commenters noted, your second version works fine, as is, so there must be some nuance in the original code that we don't see. Here is a step down to the key you care about:

```
In [45]: update = {'message': {'caption_entities': [],
    ...:              'channel_chat_created': False,
    ...:              'chat': {'first_name': 'Rodrigo Formighieri',
    ...:                       'id': 446924384,
    ...:                       'type': 'private',
    ...:                       'username': 'rodrigoformi'},
    ...:              'date': 1516040454,
    ...:              'delete_chat_photo': False,
    ...:              'entities': [{'length': 7, 'offset': 0, 'type': 'bot_command'}],
    ...:              'from': {'first_name': 'Rodrigo Formighieri',
    ...:                       'id': 446924384,
    ...:                       'is_bot': False,
    ...:                       'language_code': 'pt-BR',
    ...:                       'username': 'rodrigoformi'},
    ...:              'group_chat_created': False,
    ...:              'message_id': 145,
    ...:              'new_chat_member': None,
    ...:              'new_chat_members': [],
    ...:              'new_chat_photo': [],
    ...:              'photo': [],
    ...:              'supergroup_chat_created': False,
    ...:              'text': '/invite'},
    ...:  'update_id': 241263441}
    ...:

In [46]: update['message']
Out[46]:
{'caption_entities': [],
 'channel_chat_created': False,
 'chat': {'first_name': 'Rodrigo Formighieri',
  'id': 446924384,
  'type': 'private',
  'username': 'rodrigoformi'},
 'date': 1516040454,
 'delete_chat_photo': False,
 'entities': [{'length': 7, 'offset': 0, 'type': 'bot_command'}],
 'from': {'first_name': 'Rodrigo Formighieri',
  'id': 446924384,
  'is_bot': False,
  'language_code': 'pt-BR',
  'username': 'rodrigoformi'},
 'group_chat_created': False,
 'message_id': 145,
 'new_chat_member': None,
 'new_chat_members': [],
 'new_chat_photo': [],
 'photo': [],
 'supergroup_chat_created': False,
 'text': '/invite'}

In [47]: update['message']['from']
Out[47]:
{'first_name': 'Rodrigo Formighieri',
 'id': 446924384,
 'is_bot': False,
 'language_code': 'pt-BR',
 'username': 'rodrigoformi'}

In [48]: update['message']['from']['is_bot']
Out[48]: False
```

Comment: how you printed that? There is no nuance. def invite(bot, update): print(update["message"]["from"]["is_bot"]) this is the code, and still gives the _"NoneType' object is not subscriptable"_ error.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

```
update = ast.literal_eval(str(update))
update["message"]["from"]["is_bot"] #false
```

Had to transform cast string and then ast.literal_eval the got damn update object.